# Exclude .Library directory from `find`

Tags: find

I tried a lot of ways how to exclude **.Library** directory from `find` while trying to find something in my home directory, but it anyway prints me tons of lines with *"Permission denied"* from **Library** directory.

[image: errors]

I did it with **sudo** and from **root**, but nothing helps. I tried with `-prune`, with `-not -path` and with `grep -v`:

```
find . -name "*kate*" ! -path /Users/yves/Library
find . -name "*kate*" -path "*Library*" -prune -o -print
find . -name "*kate*" -not -path "./Library/*"
find . -name "*kate*" | grep -v Library
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `find` not to traverse the `Library` directory in the current working directory, in which case, that would be:

```
find . -path ./Library -prune -o -name '*kate*' -print
```

If it's any directory called `Library` you want to prune, not just the one in the current working directory (under `.`):

```
find . -name Library -prune -o -name '*kate*' -print
```

Doing `! -path './Library/*'` would tell find not to select the files whose path matches that pattern, but would not stop `find` from trying to traverse the `./Library` directory and its subdirectories. The only predicates that affect the way `find` traverses the directory tree are `-prune` and the non-standard (though widely supported) `-maxdepth` one.

`-depth` (and the non-standard `-delete` which implies `-depth`) affects the order of traversal (leaves before the branches they're on) and renders `-prune` ineffective. `-follow`, now superseded by the `-L` option, also affects traversal in that it instructs `find` to descend into symlinks to directories.

Comment: Man, thank you so much for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need the following syntax `find . -not -path '*/Library' -type f -name '*kate*'`. I don't know if you're looking for a folder or a file, but you'll have to change the `-type` accordingly.